# Can I travel with my passport expiring soon?

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, filipino-citizens, us-residents

Can I travel to the US with my Philippines passport, which is going to expire in May 2018? I'm a green card holder and my flight is this April.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a passport to enter the US at all, just your Green card.

So as long as your passport is valid on the day you leave the Philippines (as Philippine immigration requires it), you'll be fine.

Comment: But will the immigration of the Philippines let me go out of the country?

Comment: @Ursula Like I said, your passport only needs to be valid on the day you leave the Philippines. If they wonder, tell them you're a permanent resident of the US and that a passport isn't required to enter there, let alone a specific period of validity.

Comment: How about the 6 month rule? Is it applicable for me? Sorry for asking too many questions :) just wanna make sure. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ursula The Philippines doesn't have a 6-month rule for exit as far as I know.

Comment: @Ursula See this ("5. What are departure requirements for emigrant Philippine citizens?") You only Need a passport valid when you leave the Philippines http://www.immigration.gov.ph/faqs/travel-req